# Hide menu items from non logged in users in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hide

I need to hide this part from none logged in users:

```
if ( RDTheme::$options['header_btn_txt_mob'] && RDTheme::$options['header_btn_url'] ) {
        $html .= '<a class="header-btn header-menu-btn header-menu-btn-mob" href="'.esc_url( RDTheme::$options['header_btn_url'] ).'"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>'.esc_html( RDTheme::$options['header_btn_txt_mob'] ).'</span></a>';
    }

    if ( Helper::is_chat_enabled() ) {
        $html .= '<a class="header-chat-icon header-chat-icon-mobile rtcl-chat-unread-count" href="https://****"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
    }

    if ( RDTheme::$options['header_icon'] && class_exists( 'Rtcl' ) ) {
        $html .= '<a class="header-login-icon header-login-icon-mobile" href="'.esc_url( Link::get_my_account_page_link() ).'"><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
    }
```

And instead show this:

```
<a href="https://***" class="no_deco"><?php esc_html_e('Chat','classima'); ?></a>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```